# Gatsby: images added in MDX don't have blurring up effects when loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am using `gatsby-plugin-mdx` along with `gatsby-remark-images` to incorporate images in MDX for blogging and it is supposed to have the blur up effects which come with Gatsby Image by default

Here is how I config the plugin in my `gatsby-config.js`

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [".mdx", ".md"],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 500,
              showCaptions: ["title", "alt"],
              quality: 50,
              withWebp: true,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
            options: {
              wrapperStyle: `margin-bottom: 1.0725rem`,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-vscode`,
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files`,
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-smartypants`,
          },
        ],
        plugins: [{ resolve: "gatsby-remark-images" }],
      },
    },
```

It does convert my images to webp and optimize the quality using `srcSet` and other stuff but it doesn't have the blur up effects. I wonder how do I make it blur up when loading as a Gatsby Image would normally

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions in [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/mdx/plugins/)?

> `gatsby-source-filesystem` needs to be pointed at wherever you have your images on disk, gatsby-remark-images needs to be both a sub-plugin of gatsby-plugin-mdxand a string entry in the plugins array, and gatsby-plugin-sharp can be included on its own.

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-remark-images`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1035,
              sizeByPixelDensity: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

In your `gatsby-config.js`, it looks like you're missing `gatsby-plugin-sharp`, and possibly `gatsby-source-filesystem` (you probably already have it elsewhere in your config if the images are sourced).

You're also resolving the `gatsby-remark-images` plugin under the `options` in `gatsby-plugin-mdx`, but it should only be in the main `plugins` array and under `gatsbyRemarkPlugins`.

Comment: Thanks - what fixed it for me is adding `gatsby-remark-images` in the `plugins` array. (It was already in `gatsbyRemarkPlugins`.